# PGFPlots consistent multiplier at ticks labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels, ticks

I need a little help with multiplier format in the PGFplots. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\begin{document}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%,
        \begin{axis}[
            scaled ticks=false,
            clip mode=individual, %
            width=0.55\columnwidth,%
            scale only axis,%
            tick style={color=black},%
            minor y tick num=3,%
            ylabel style={align=center,rotate=-90,overlay},%
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,std,sci zerofill,precision=1,overlay},%
            ytick align=inside,%
            axis y line*=left,%
            minor x tick num=3,%
            xlabel style={align=center,text width=2.5cm},%
            xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0},%
            xtick align=inside,%
            axis x line*=bottom,%
            ymin=0, ymax=0.000014,%
            xmin=273.15, xmax=374.15,%
            ]%
            \addplot[domain=273.15:373.15,samples=100]{0.01*101325*((3.6*10^(-7))*(e^(2200*(1/x-1/298.15))))/(-13.85100+0.64038*x-0.00191*x^2+0.00000182110*x^3)};
            \addplot[green,domain=273.15:373.15,samples=100]{0.001*101325*((3.6*10^(-7))*(e^(2200*(1/x-1/298.15))))/(-13.85100+0.64038*x-0.00191*x^2+0.00000182110*x^3)};
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

which leads to the plot:
[image]

and I would like to have a consistent scientific multiplier through the range of the y-axis. I mean multiplier with same order, 10^5 or 10^6, not both as it's now and of course i don't want to have one multiplier at the top of the y-axis as it can be easily done.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my answer below I scaled each `y tick` with a certain `\exponent` of base 10. See the comments in the code for an explanation. For the moment it only works if `\tick` (after rescaling) is larger than 1. If you try `\newcommand{\exponent}{5}` it will set the `y labels` which are <1 to 0, because of `int(\tick)`.

Some other things:

- I could not run your code with `\usepackage{tikz}`. You use the `axis` environment, then you need `\usepackage{pgfplots}` I think.
- You can replace `axis y line*=left` and `axis x line*=bottom` with `axis lines*= left` with the same result.
- You can replace `minor y tick num=3` and `minor x tick num=3` with `minor tick num=3` with the same result.
- I'm not sure why you redefine the `axis label` styles. They do not change if I remove them.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
% Define the exponent of base 10, where to divide each y label with
\newcommand{\exponent}{6}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%,
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.55\columnwidth,%
            scale only axis,%
            tick style={color=black}, axis lines*= left,%
            minor tick num=3,%
            % Scale each y label with a certain exponent
            scaled y ticks=base 10:\exponent,
            % Hide the corresponding scaling label ($10^-\exponent$)
            ytick scale label code/.code={},
            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}
                % If the tick = 0, just put 0
                \ifnum \pgfmathresult = 0 
                    0
                % Else print the scaled number adding 10^\exponent to each tick
                \else
                    \pgfmathresult $\cdot 10^{-\exponent}$
                \fi},
            ymin=0, ymax=0.000014,%
            xmin=273.15, xmax=374.15,%
            ]%
            \addplot[domain=273.15:373.15,samples=100]{0.01*101325*((3.6*10^(-7))*(e^(2200*(1/x-1/298.15))))/(-13.85100+0.64038*x-0.00191*x^2+0.00000182110*x^3)};
            \addplot[green,domain=273.15:373.15,samples=100]{0.001*101325*((3.6*10^(-7))*(e^(2200*(1/x-1/298.15))))/(-13.85100+0.64038*x-0.00191*x^2+0.00000182110*x^3)};
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

### Result

Using `width=10 cm`:

[image]